# How to set all unmasked values to a certain value?

Tags: python, numpy

In Python I have a masked array, `mask_array`, and I want to set all remaining (unmasked) values to 1. When I do `mask_array[(mask_array >= 0) & (mask_array < 0)= 1`, the cells keep their original values and do not change to 1. When I do `mask_array[mask_array>=0]=1`, all cells including those I had masked originally change to 1. Why is this the case?

Is there a solution?

Comment: Please share an input example, the expected output and the actual output, share a snipper of code that can be easily reproduced by us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `(mask_array >= 0) & (mask_array < 0)` can't match any cell. No value inside `mask_array` can be *bigger or equal to 0* **and** *smaller than 0* at the same time, so nothing matches => no changes

Comment: Thanks, I used separate lines of code for values greater and less than 0, and that worked

Comment: @madschm if the answer satisfies you, you can accept the answer (green tick on the left). Also I'd be curious to see what is inside `mask_array` and what you expect of it. That's a common a adviced practice to specify in the initial post, the code and the expected output